# TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm currently facing this error message at login, my registration function works fine. but can't seem to figure out why my login keeps bringing this error. I would appreciate if I can be pointed to where my mistake is coming from.

```
void loginUser() async {
    User user;
    await _auth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email.text, password: password.text)
        .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
      return value;
    }).catchError((error) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      Get.defaultDialog(title: 'Error in Login');
    });
    if (user != null) {
      readData(user).then((value) => Get.toNamed(homeRoute));
    }
  }

  Future readData(User user) async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .get()
        .then((result) async {
      await App.sharedPreferences.setString('uid', result.get('uid'));
      await App.sharedPreferences.setString('email', result.get('email'));
      await App.sharedPreferences.setString('fullname', result.get('fullname'));
      await App.sharedPreferences.setString('bvn', result.get('bvn'));
    });
  }
```

Here's my Registration function

```
 void _registerUser() async {
    User user;
    await _auth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email.text, password: password.text)
        .then((value) {
      user = value.user;
    }).catchError((error) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      Get.defaultDialog(title: 'Error in registration');
    });
    if (user != null) {
      saveToFirestore(user).then((value) => Get.toNamed(homeRoute));
    }
  }

  Future saveToFirestore(User user) async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
      'uid': user.uid,
      'fullname': fullname.text.trim(),
      'email': user.email,
      'bvn': bvn.text
    });

    await App.sharedPreferences.setString('uid', user.uid);
    await App.sharedPreferences.setString('email', user.email);
    await App.sharedPreferences.setString('fullname', fullname.text);
    await App.sharedPreferences.setString('bvn', bvn.text);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
  User user;
    await _auth
```

to `User user = await _auth....`

And in your FireStore query, use

```
 Future readData(User user) async {
   FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users') 
      .doc(user.user.uid) // instead of user.uid
      .get()
```

Everywhere with `user.uid` change it to `user.user.uid`.